# Git Hub Actions Error - fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Tags: junit, github-actions, cicd

I am new to GitHub Actions and I am just trying to use the 'Test Reporter' action in my workflow.

These are my steps:

```
- name: Test
    env:
      SERVER_PATH: ${{ github.workspace }}/drop/${{ env.PATH}}
    run: mvn --batch-mode -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true test --file ${{ env.PATH }}/pom.xml
    
- name: Test Report
    env:
      SERVER_PATH: ${{ github.workspace }}/drop/${{ env.PATH}}
    uses: dorny/test-reporter@v1
    if: always()
    with:
      name: Maven Tests
      path: target/surefire-reports/*.xml
      reporter: java-junit
      fail-on-error: true`
```

The test step works as expected, I am only getting an error in the test report step.

***Error***:

```
    Check runs will be created with 
    SHA=589c5f9c5b663f851f3f9bd49fbc66a00634183c
    Listing all files tracked by git
    /usr/bin/git ls-files -z
    fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
  
    Error: Error: The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128
```

Please help!

Update: Feb 6, 2023:

```
    Test Report
Run dorny/test-reporter@v1
  with:
    name: Maven Tests
    path: target/surefire-reports/*.xml
    reporter: java-junit
    fail-on-error: true
    path-replace-backslashes: false
    list-suites: all
    list-tests: all
    max-annotations: 10
    only-summary: false
    token: ***
  env:
    APPCONFIGRGP: appconfig
    APPCONFIGSKU: Standard
    BACKENDPATH: MyApp

    JAVA_HOME_8.0.362_x64: /home/azureuser/actions-runner/_work/_tool/jdk/8.0.362/x64
    JAVA_HOME: /home/azureuser/actions-runner/_work/_tool/jdk/8.0.362/x64
    JAVA_HOME_8_0_362_X64: /home/azureuser/actions-runner/_work/_tool/jdk/8.0.362/x64
    SERVER_PATH: /home/azureuser/actions-runner/_work/App/App/temp/App
Check runs will be created with SHA=05410264d739b3ccb57fe740d230cd4b428ef605
Listing all files tracked by git
  /usr/bin/git ls-files -z
  fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
  
Error: Error: The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128
```

Comment: Is that your complete workflow?

Comment: Two things that come to mind: 1. Did you include a checkout action before this? Seems like it needs the code to get info from. 2. Check if your repository uses the repo setting for giving the GITHUB_TOKEN read only access? That went live last week.

Comment: @Azeem no, this isn't my complete workflow. the workflow is actually pre-existing and is quite big. I can post other bits here if they'll be helpful.

Comment: @RobBos Thank you for commenting! The checkout should already be part of the test, so I am not sure why it needs checkout for the reports. I just tried to base this off this example here - https://github.com/dorny/test-reporter. Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Regarding GITHUB_TOKEN, I don't think I have access to view that. I don't see a Settings tab in my repo!

Comment: As per your last comment, did you mean there's no checkout step before running tests? If yes, you need to checkout the code first to do anything on it. The official example also has this (https://github.com/dorny/test-reporter#example). For any action that works with code, the code needs to be checked out first.

Comment: @Azeem No, but I have an artifact downloaded previously that's being used by the test.
`- name: Download Build Artifacts
       uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
       with:
         name: temp
         path: temp`

Comment: @Kikrigen: So, you don't need the code at all? But, the error "**fatal: not a git repository**" occurred because it's not a git repo. Please update that error along with the step title i.e. copy/paste the output of step (only the relevant parts).

Comment: Also, you might want to verify the existing issues and [create an issue](https://github.com/dorny/test-reporter/issues/new/choose) on that repo if one doesn't exist.

Comment: @Azeem no, the code should already be available unless I am specifying the path wrong, because I can see my test names etc. in the GHA logs. 

I've updated the original post to include relevant logs as requested. Thank you :)

Comment: @Kikrigen: It's failing while running `/usr/bin/git ls-files -z` command which means it's looking for a git repo. You current path doesn't look right if the code is already checked out. You can run `pwd` and `ls` commands to verify that.

Comment: @Azeem I am unable to use run to do ls or pwd because 'uses' is being used. How do I get around this?

Comment: @Kikrigen: You can add another step in between and run those commands to verify this.